# Mobile app authentication using Token based on OAuth2.0

Tags: rest, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm building a REST API using Elixir's Phoenix framework. In the API, I need to authenticate the user by phone number i.e., via sending an SMS OTP code. After authenticating the user, the Auth server sends the Access token and Refresh token to the client. The client(mobile app) stores those tokens locally and sends the Access token in the HTTP header as `Authorization: Bearer <Access_Token>` in every request to resource server. My actual question is, how do resource server validates the Access token that is received from the mobile app/client?

Does resource server needs to contact Auth server to validate the Access Token? That would a lot of overhead. Please help me understand RestFull API Authentication.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Y'know, you don't **need** to use Bearer Tokens to secure a web-service. I'm personally not a fan of Bearer Tokens because you can only safely use them in a secure communications channel. Have you considered using signed-requests instead?

Comment: Also, authentication schemes have little to do with REST, and vice-versa. REST is specific technical term with specific _narrow_ technical and theoretical definitions that are concerned with how application state is represented and managed over a given transport - you can use Bearer Tokens with non-REST web-services and you *can* use  stateful authentication systems with otherwise stateless REST web-services.

Comment: I've not heard of signed-requests so far, could you please tell me more about it or a blog/link would really help.

Comment: You can't get more canonical than the draft RFC for OAuth's signed requests feature: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-signed-http-request-03 - though the concept of signed-requests dates back to _at least_ the (now deprecated) HTTP Digest authentication scheme. Though I'm sure there are other schemes that use signed transactions for authentication that predate HTTP (a very good example would be the [US EAM system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_Action_Message), which demonstrates the necessity for a _distributed_ and _decentralised_ authentication system).

Comment: Historically, the same concept of _signed messages_ that required an existing _trust relationship_ goes back literally centuries [because that's how the banking systems of the world worked in medieval times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UE7nd36EpRU).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have everything working up to validating the token. You are going to need the public key for the server that signed the token. It depends on what auth server you're working with on how you get that. In some cases you may be able to preload this key as a configuration setting on your backend. Otherwise you can probably get it via https request to the auth server. Most auth servers these days I expect to provide a JWKS api that you can use to get the keys you need. Then with the token and the public key you can use your elixir jwt library to validate that the token you have was signed by the server you trust, meaning the SMS code was validated, and you can proceed with whatever is needed in the backend to handle the request.

If you're using Joken for elixir you can review https://hexdocs.pm/joken_jwks/introduction.html and https://hexdocs.pm/joken/introduction.html for more information.

Comment: can I try using `mix phx.gen.secret` to generate a key and store the key on both Auth server and Resource server for validation., ie., sign a token using that key on Auth server and verify the access token on resource server?

Comment: hmm, no you need a different kind of key. Are you implementing the Auth server? You would probably be better off with an off the shelf idp like keycloak or identityserver4

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing custom Auth server for my needs, that's why it's taking a long time :(

Answer (score 0):

> how do resource server validates the Access token that is received from the mobile app/client?

The same way a nightclub bouncer verifies your driving license as proof-of-age to let you in: by validating the authority and signatures, but it does not need to phone-up your DMV to verify that your license is real because it *trusts* the signatures (in this case, cryptographic signatures).

That said, some systems *do* use "reference tokens" which are short (say 32 bytes) of *meaningless random data* which are used as an unpredictable record identifier for some user-permissions record held by the authorization server. The resource-server will need to contact the auth server initially, but then it can simply cache the auth result itself for some time window.

Comment: thanks for your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488254/mobile-app-authentication-using-token-based-on-oauth2-0?noredirect=1#comment115780332_65488254), it really did shine some light on my confusion. But how do traditional mobile app's Authentication works with out Bearer tokens. Can you please share an URL explaining the procedure(an example). I'm kinda new to backend stuff, I'm more of a frontend person, now doing backend work.

Comment: @Rick I'd wager most (non-SOAP) web-services today using a distributed identity model **do** use bearer-tokens because it's straightforward and simple, and well-established (OAuth2/OIDC is primarily built-around bearer tokens).

Comment: I can't "give you a URL" because "AuthX" (short for "authentication and authorization") is a **huge** topic that took me years to fully understand.

Comment: ok, let's forget about bearer tokens for a second.. what would be a best solution for mobile app authentication using phone number(sms otp code).

Comment: @Rick I wouldn't use phone-numbers or SMS at all, it's insecure and doesn't actually prove or establish anything necessary for any kind of trustworthy authentication scheme (it only "proves" that someone had the ability to access a someone's phone or acount for a minute). It would help if you could explain what your web-service actually does or why you think you need to use some form of phone-number or SMS-based auth system. Who are your users? What are they trying to accomplish? What are the actual security requirements?

Comment: I [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65488254/mobile-app-authentication-using-token-based-on-oauth2-0/65488320?noredirect=1#comment115780709_65488320) understand the pain.. I've been stuck with it for almost 6 months now

Comment: Ok, I'll follow traditional username/email & password login system in my app. Thanks man I really appreciate your help.. I'll comeback to this answer in the future for learning more about signed-requests.

Comment: "I'll follow traditional username/email & password login system in my app" - uhm - if you have a web-service ("web API") you still need an authx system - I don't see how that solves your problem. The rise in popularity for "phone-number authentication" is more to reduce _user friction_ with registration (and cynically, to collect personal contact data...) than it is to have good security: it's much easier to type-in a phone-number *for use as a username* than it is to try to think-up an unused username or type-in a long e-mail address, especially amongst unsophisticated users.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't solve my problem, but I did learned some thing new from you. Sorry for asking you again, how can I solve my problem? could you please teach me a bit

Comment: "could you please teach me a bit" - as much as I'd love to pontificate, as I said, this topic is simply too large. You're far better-off convincing your boss to let you do a professional training course in OIDC or something, e.g. https://www.udemy.com/course/openid-connect/ (well, that's more of a "how to use OIDC" course, not a "theory and fundamentals of OIDC" course) for that you might want to consider https://www.okta.com/training/sso-enable-custom-apps-and-sites-with-oidc